# Why do I need the extra dot notation when passing an array to a prop in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm newer to React.js and JavaScript syntax, but didn't find a question answering the syntax I'm confused by in the below, so here it goes!

When using an array in React.js, why do I need to use additional dot notation on the passed prop to call a property within an array?

For example, In the `Content` component, why do I have to type `part.parts[0].name`  in the below when in Java/C# I could just type `parts[0].name` ? If I don't do the above, I get a *"**parts[0].name is undefined**"* error.

The below code is from an exercise, so the intent is for me to sort through the weird logic and fix bugs as an exercise in correcting bad code. It's not pretty, but my solution below runs OK and there is more code that I'm not including, and I'm wondering why I have to use the additional dot notation... any explanation appreciated!

Let me know if my logic is wrong (and the structure of the code is terrible, I know), but if I'm passing the '`course.parts`' array directly to the `Content` component, shouldn't JavaScript be able to grab the `name` and `exercises` properties when I pass the individual `part` to the `Part` component?

```
 const App = () => {
      const course = {
        name: 'Half Stack application development',
        parts: [
            {
            number: '1'
            name: 'Fundamentals of React',
            exercises: 10
          },
          {
            number: '2'
            name: 'Using props to pass data',
            exercises: 7
          },
          {
            number: '3'
            name: 'State of a component',
            exercises: 14
          }
        ]
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Header course={course.name} />
          <Content parts={course.parts} />
          <Total parts={course.parts} />
        </div>
      )
    }

const Part = (part) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Part {part.number}: {part.name}</h2>
      <h3>{part.exercises} exercises</h3>
    </>
      )
}
    
    const Content = (parts) => {
      console.log(parts[0])
      return (
        <>
          <Part part={parts[0]} name={parts.parts[0].name} exercises={parts.parts[0].exercises} number={parts.parts[0].number} />
        </>
       )
     }
```

Comment: When you call a component in React you pass in an _object_ as "props". `const Part = (part)` should really be `const Part = ({ part })` where you destructure the property `part` from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument passed to a component function is an **object** with properties for each of the component's props. So if you call:

```
<Content parts={x} />
```

...the `Content` function is called with an object with a `parts` property on it. That's so if there are *other* properties, they can be passed all together.

It's fairly common with react function components to use *object destructuring* to pick out the desired props, like this:

```
const Content = ({parts}) => {
//               ^−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− object destructuring
    return (
        <>
            <Part part={parts[0]} name={parts[0].name} exercises={parts[0].exercises} number={parts[0].number} />
        </>
    );
};
```

That's functionally equivalent to:

```
const Content = (props) => {
    const parts = props.parts;
    return (
        <>
            <Part part={parts[0]} name={parts[0].name} exercises={parts[0].exercises} number={parts[0].number} />
        </>
    );
};
```

---

Side note: There's no need to use a fragment when you're returning just one element:

```
const Content = ({parts}) => {
    return <Part part={parts[0]} name={parts[0].name} exercises={parts[0].exercises} number={parts[0].number} />;
};
```

or

```
const Content = ({parts}) => {
    return <Part
        part={parts[0]}
        name={parts[0].name}
        exercises={parts[0].exercises}
        number={parts[0].number}
    />;
};
```

And if you're already passing the part, then it seems unnecessary to pass `name`, `exercises`, and `number` separately; `Part` should be able to get them from the object it receives as its `part` property. WHich would give us:

```
const Content = ({parts}) => {
    return <Part part={parts[0]} />;
};
```

Comment: This was a very awesome explanation, thank you! That bottom piece of code looks MUCH cleaner, and is exactly what I was looking for --- still a newb at React here and appreciate your insights!

Answer (score 0):

All the passed data are stored in a props object. You have to access the passed key like parts in your case through props object. You can use destructuring like const Part = ({ parts }) =>. Take some time and read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I like the idea of having to do less deciphering/trace-back for future engineers, and destructing feels like the right choice. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Content parts={course.parts} />
```

Basically in React, this line means a function that has parameter object like `function(params)` and in that line, it will be like `Content({ parts: course.parts })`

so your code `const Content = (parts) => {...}` is the function that accept that params.

To make it more understandable. you can rename the `parts` in the bracket to be `params` or usually `props` in React.

so `props` is an object.. you can do something like this instead..

`const Content = ({ parts }) => {...}` which means destructing (ES6 way) the object to the parts. then you can use it directly `parts[0].name`

Sorry for the weird explanation.

Comment: Not weird, I followed that logic! Thank you, that helps a lot. I'll likely have to get more familiar with destructing, but it feels more readable the ES6 way you mentioned than constantly having 'props' in front of everything... or maybe that's just me! Thanks for the reply